# Having an issue detecting problem in my code | CUDA c

Tags: cuda

I'm having a hard time understanding where is the bug in my code.

The purpose of the project is to multiply two matrices and compare the time between sequential and parallel.

When I'm printing the Matrices I see that the device matrix is basically empty.

Also, I treated the matrices as an array of size n*n .

Thanks!

```
//This program computes the multiplication of two Matrices  GPU using CUDA

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>


__global__ void matrixMul(int * m,int * n,int * p,int size)
{
    //Calculate Row and Column
   int row=threadIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int column=threadIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   int p_sum=0;

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      p_sum += m[row*size + i] * n[i*size +column];

   }
   p[row*size + column] = p_sum;

}

void matrixMul_seq(int * m,int * n,int * p,int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
                p[i*size +j] += m[i*size +k] +n[k*size +j];
            }
        }
    }
}



//Initialize matricies
void init_matricies(int * mat,int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            mat[i*n+j]=rand()%1024;
        }
        
    }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

   //Set our problem Size(Default = 2^10 == 1024)
   int n = 1<<10;
   printf("Square Matrix of size:%d\n",n);

   //Size in Bytes
   size_t bytes=n*n*sizeof(bytes);

   //Host matricies
   int *h_m;
   int *h_p;    
   int *h_n;
   int *h_p_seq;
   //Host matricies
   int *d_m;
   int *d_p;    
   int *d_n;


   //Memory allocation for Host Matricies
   h_m=(int*)malloc(bytes);
   h_n=(int*)malloc(bytes);
   h_p=(int*)malloc(bytes);
   h_p_seq=(int*)malloc(bytes);



   init_matricies(h_m,n);
   init_matricies(h_n,n);

   //Allocate memory on device side
   cudaMalloc(&d_n, bytes);
   cudaMalloc(&d_m, bytes);
   cudaMalloc(&d_p, bytes);

   //Copy data to Device
   cudaMemcpy(d_m,h_m, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(d_n,h_n, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    
   int threads_per_block =16;
   dim3 block_size(threads_per_block,threads_per_block);
   dim3 grid_size( n / block_size.x , n / block_size.y);

   printf("Grid size  X:%d, Grid size y:%d\n",grid_size.x,grid_size.y);
   printf("THE RESULT OF THE SIZES: 2^6 * 2^4 * 2^6 * 2^4  \n");

   matrixMul <<<grid_size,block_size>>>(d_m,d_n,d_p,n);
   matrixMul_seq(h_m,h_n,h_p_seq,n);
   cudaMemcpy(h_p,d_p, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);   

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        //printf("Grid size  X:%d, Grid size y:%d\n",h_p[ n * i + j],h_p_seq[ n * i + j]);

            assert(h_p[ n * i + j]==h_p_seq[ n * i + j]);
    }
 }
    free(h_m);
    free(h_p);
    free(h_n);
    free(h_p_seq);

    cudaFree(d_m);
    cudaFree(d_n);
    cudaFree(d_p);
  

     return 0;
  

}
```

Comment: I see no device memory allocation for any of those three arrays on the GPU. How do you imagine this could work without them?

Comment: what do you mean??  there's an allocation to all of them

Comment: size_t bytes=n*n*sizeof(bytes);
    h_m=(int*)malloc(bytes);
       h_n=(int*)malloc(bytes);
       h_p=(int*)malloc(bytes);
       h_p_seq=(int*)malloc(bytes);   cudaMemcpy(d_m,h_m, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
       cudaMemcpy(d_n,h_n, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);        cudaMemcpy(h_p,d_p, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

Comment: There is no allocation of `d_m`, `d_n`, or `d_p` anywhere in that code

Comment: @talonmies you were right, I did not notice. but the assert function returns an error which I can't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variety of problems in your code:

1. You are calculating kernel index variables incorrectly.  This is incorrect:

   ```
   int row=threadIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
   int column=threadIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   ```

   it should be:

   ```
   int row=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
   int column=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   ```
2. The matrix operations in your calculation functions don't match each other.  Kernel:

   ```
   p_sum += m[row*size + i] * n[i*size +column];
                            ^
                            multiplication
   ```

   host code:

   ```
   p[i*size +j] += m[i*size +k] +n[k*size +j];
                                ^
                                addition
   ```

   we also observe, from above, that the host code is doing a *summation to* the output variable (`+=`), whereas the the kernel is doing an *assignment* to the output variable (`=`):

   ```
   p[row*size + column] = p_sum;
   ```

   This has implications for the next issue.
3. `malloc` doesn't initialize data.  Since this operation is creating the output array that will be used by the host code, which is doing a summation to it, we must initialize this allocation to zero:

   ```
   h_p_seq=(int*)malloc(bytes);
   memset(h_p_seq, 0, bytes);  // must add this line to initialize to zero
   ```
4. The calculation of the size of your arrays in bytes is too large.  You have defined your arrays to be of type `int`.  But your size calculation is like this:

   ```
   size_t bytes=n*n*sizeof(bytes);
   ```

   An `int` is a 4-byte quantity, whereas a `size_t` variable like `bytes` is an 8-byte quantity.  This doesn't cause an actual problem, but is unnecessary.  I would suggest changing it to:

   ```
   size_t bytes=n*n*sizeof(int);
   ```

With the above items addressed, your code runs correctly for me.